# Determining position in a list (variable) of a case in R

Tags: r

How to determine numerical position of a case in a vector?

I have a variable e.g., `Var` with multiple cases:

```
Case_1    <- 22
Case_2    <- 33
Case_3    <- 155
Case_4    <- 321
Var <- cbind(c(Case_1,Case_2,Case_3, Case_4))
names(Var) <- c("Case_1","Case_2","Case_3", "Case_4")
Var <- sort(Var, decreasing = TRUE)
```

I want to know the position of a case in this list (in this instance – `Case 4` is position `1`, `Case_3` is position `2`, etc. How can I do it in R?

Comment: Please complete the example to make it reproducible

Comment: I submitted an edit it to make it reproducible; cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 ways:

> ```
> Case_1    <- 22
> Case_2    <- 33
> Case_3    <- 155
> Case_4    <- 321
> Var <- cbind(c(Case_1,Case_2,Case_3, Case_4))
> names(Var) <- c("Case_1","Case_2","Case_3", "Case_4")
> Var <- sort(Var, decreasing = TRUE)
>
> # By Value
> n <- which(Var == 321)
> cat("The position with a value of 321 is", n)
> ```
>
> The position with a value of 321 is 1
>
> ```
> # By Name
> n <- which(names(Var) == "Case_1")
> cat("The position with of Case_1 is", n)
> ```
>
> The position with of Case_1 is 4

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `match()` function:

```
myvec <- letters

> myvec
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

 > match('e',myvec)
[1] 5
```

And you get the index this way.

As for your example:

```
Var <- read.table(header=F, text= "Case_1    22
Case_2    33
Case_3    155
Case_4    321")

Var <- Var[order(Var$V1, decreasing=T), ] #sort it decreasing

> match('Case_4',Var$V1)
[1] 1
```

Comment: `match('qatarflights',sort(di, decreasing = T))
[1] NA`
For some reason I get `NA` instead of a position.

Comment: I think it might be a problem of sorting. Try sorting your data frame first and then use match at the beginning to see how it works. Also, make sure 'qatarflights' is also lower case in your data.frame. R is case sensitive.